# Trino helm chart audit log configuration

Tags: kubernetes-helm, trino, audit-logging

I am using this [Trino Community Chart](https://github.com/trinodb/charts) to deploy trino in kubernetes. I can't find any way to configure elasticsearch for writing audit log. Traditional way of configuring it is to set XAAUDIT.ELASTICSEARCH properties in install.properties. I was wondering if there is a way to set this up in different way in trino version 720.

There is a way to pass additional properties through values but I am not sure what they should be. I am not able to find any documentation about it.